# ConvertTo-XML doesn't display as expected

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In a foreach loop, I am trying to gather information about a number of objects, and concatenate them all in one XML file.

```
foreach($Task in $Tasks) {            
    $OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject             
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer            

    # does not work, $s contains '#document'
    $s = ConvertTo-XML -InputObject $OutputObj
    Write-Host $s   
    # works as expected
    $OutputObj | Export-CliXML $OutPath  
}
```

What am I doing wrong with `ConvertTo-XML`?  How can I get it to produce the output that `Export-CliXML`? To be clear, I want to convert each `$outputobj` and append it to the output file.

Comment: Adding "-As Stream" helps, but then each $s is a discrete xml doc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
($Tasks | ForEach-Object {
    $OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer
    Write-Output $OutputObj
} | ConvertTo-XML -NoTypeInformation).Save($OutPath)
```

or this:

```
$combined = @()
foreach($Task in $Tasks) {            
    $OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject             
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer

    $combined += $OutputObj
}
$combined | Export-CliXML $OutPath
```

What a result do you want to see?
To learn more about ConvertTo-XML read the article "Dress Up Your XML Output with the ConvertTo-XML Cmdlet" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730921.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$s = ConvertTo-XML -InputObject $OutputObj
```

Try

```
$s = $OutputObj | ConvertTo-XML
```

I have the same problem with ConvertTo-CSV.  The -InputObject parameter is not working as I expect.  But piping the object(s) to the ConvertTo-CSV works as expected.